# Remove hour ticks

Tags: d3.js

I'm trying to draw a time scale on an X-axis using D3JS and I have a problem removing "hour ticks".

```
// set the dimensions and margins of the graph
var margin = {top: 10, right: 30, bottom: 30, left: 40},
width = 460 - margin.left - margin.right,
height = 400 - margin.top - margin.bottom;

// append the svg object to the body of the page
var svg = d3.select("#chart")
    .append("svg")
    .attr("width", width + margin.left + margin.right)
    .attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
    .append("g")
    .attr("transform",
      "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");

// X axis: scale and draw:
var x = d3.scaleTime()
    .domain([new Date('2021-03-15T00:00:00'), new Date('2021-03-21T00:00:00')])
    .range([0, 400])
    .nice();

svg.append("g")
    .attr("transform", "translate(0," + height + ")")
    .call(d3.axisBottom(x));
```

And I have this as results:
[image: The "hour ticks" that I mentioned are those I circled in red]

The "hour ticks" that I mentioned are those which I circled in red. How do I change my code to remove only these ticks and leave only the "day ticks"?
Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

D3 will try to automatically add a reasonable amount of ticks to the line. If you want to control manually how many ticks to see use the `ticks` property.

For example with `ticks(5)` you get only days (for a 5 day `scaleTime`):

[image]